# How can I post a new lead with a fully back end solution?

Tags: rest-api, authentication

I'm completely new to Salesforce, but this seems like a normal usage case but I can't seem to understand how this might work by reading their docs.

I have a website that has a form that people can fill out, and depending on how they fill it out I want to be able to send that info to SF as a new lead. I can see how to do that if the user signs in, but this is for the general public so they won't have SF logins. It is all handled on the back end.

How can I set it up so I can authenticate my app's back end to sign in to SF and post the new lead via the API? It's a node app, so I would prefer the REST API.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use Web-to-Lead for this?

Comment: @AlexTennant I personally *wouldn't*, if I had a choice. The low daily limit, the risk of automated spammers getting your org ID, etc, all make it a bit less reliable than simply building a nice, secure form with a captcha of some sort. Make those spammers work to send you leads.

Comment: @sdfcfox That's what I get for commenting on my phone. I was thinking about calling Web-to-Lead from the back-end rather than the front-end (and exposing the Org ID). I see you've covered that in your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you didn't want to use web-to-lead for some reason (limits on per-day usage, etc), there are still a number of ways you could interact with salesforce.com "on the back end."

Here's some typical examples:

Build an OAuth2 prompt on your app in some admin panel. Have it get a refresh token and complete the OAuth2 dance, then use the provided access token to send those leads to salesforce.com via the REST API. Store the refresh token securely to avoid account compromise. I'd just making it a minimal permission (e.g. read and create leads only, web API user, no unnecessary permissions) in case you were compromised.

Build an InboundEmailHandler. Send your lead via SMTP to the designated address for your handler, and it can create leads for you. There is a limit on this interface (1,000 times the number of full licenses you have), but this is far better than the 500/day limit for leads. You don't even need to store any authentication data at all, and if your email address were compromised, you could change it fairly easily.

Build an unauthenticated, write-only API using Sites. You can expose REST methods through Sites, and call them as you would any other API, but without needing authentication (they will masquerade as the Site user). Keep your handler simple, and avoid exposing data.

You could even take most of these options above and make them bulk. Save a few leads, and every 15 minutes, send whatever you have to Salesforce.com. For example, InboundEmailHandlers have a pretty high ceiling for memory, so you could batch a handful of records together and not worry too much about governor-related errors.

There's a ton of great information on [DeveloperForce](http://www.developerforce.com/) regarding everything I've mentioned here, including full documents, examples, forums, blogs with various examples, and so on. You can also read some of the less technical details, like setting up Sites, in the Help & Training window as well.

I've also personally integrated salesforce.com using a back-end script to send to web-to-lead. This avoids exposing your org ID, which, once found, means that spammers can try to fill your queues with bad leads (and hit your 500/day limit). There's other ways to combat this, certainly, but not exposing your org ID to the outside world is a great first step.

Comment: So it sounds like my issue was that I've got a round hole and the API is a square peg. I'll take a look at the email handler and web-to-lead on the back end. We only get a few messages a day that would go to the form, so I doubt I'll run into any limits any time soon. Thanks!